# What exactly is covered with this Icelandic car rental?

Tags: car-rentals, insurance, iceland

We're going to have an one-week trip to Iceland in March. As we want to travel around the island, we decided to rent a small car. But I'm not sure if everything is covered by the offered insurance:

The car rental company (a broker for a local company) offers "Fully comprehensive insurance without excess" and "Theft protection without excess". You would have to pay a possible excess locally, but you can get a refund by the rental company at home. As an extra, you can book a "glass & tires" package.

Any insurance for sand & ash damages has to be bought locally with some excess - **is this still refundable by the rental company? And is there any gravel protection package? Do we need that SCDW package anyways?**

For clarity, here are the specific parts of the rental terms:

> This partner offers you an insurance with reimbursement of the excess.
>   In case of damage or theft of the vehicle, the deposit will be
>   retained by the landlord as a deductible. After returning the car,
>   send the invoice to our partners in due time and the amount will be
>   refunded to you.
>
> Additional insurances on site: If you are already insured by our
>   partner Auto Europe with a' fully comprehensive insurance policy
>   without excess', you do not need to take out any additional insurance
>   locally.
>
> The complete rental conditions for this offer:
>
> Excess in case of damage: ISK 195,000.00, incl. VAT.
>
> Super CDW: ISK 2,300.00, per day, incl. VAT, payable on site.
>
> Reduces the collision deductible to ISK 25,000.00.
>
> Sand and Ash Protection: Approximately ISK 1,900.00, per day, incl.
>   VAT, payable on site. Excess applies of approximately ISK 195,000.00,
>   incl. VAT.
>
> CDW does not cover damages caused by sandstorms.
>
> Excess in case of theft: Approx. ISK 195,000.00, incl. VAT.
>
> PAI: Included in rates. Liability Insurance: Included in rates.
>
> Fire Insurance: Included in all rates.
>
> Auto Europe LLC has arranged your car rental booking with the car
>   rental company listed on your voucher. Auto Europe LLC acts as an
>   agency between you and the specified car rental company. For the
>   purpose of car rental, Auto Europe LLC has accepted the payment of
>   your reservation on behalf of the specified car rental company. This
>   voucher is not a rental agreement and Auto Europe LLC itself is not a
>   car rental company. At the time of renting, you enter into a rental
>   agreement with the above-mentioned car rental company, which is
>   subject to local legislation. Auto Europe LLC shall not be liable for
>   any failure to comply with the above-mentioned car rental company's
>   requirements or for any documents not available but necessary for
>   rental. Additional fees can be charged by the car rental company on
>   site, if this is the case. If the rental vehicle is picked up or
>   returned outside of opening hours or additional services are requested
>   on site, these fees are listed on your voucher in the rental terms and
>   conditions of the car rental company in the local currency. The rental
>   price is guaranteed in the above mentioned currency. All additional
>   local charges not included in the rental price will be charged
>   directly by the car rental company according to the local currency of
>   the rental agreement/terms and conditions. As Auto Europe LLC acts as
>   an intermediary, it is not possible to report VAT invoices. Auto
>   Europe LLC, 39 Commercial Street, Portland, ME 04101 is a Limited
>   Liability Company registered